# Diaconescu theorem clarification

Tags: set-theory

There is one step of the proof of Diaconescu's theorem I don't understand.

Proposition: The axiom of choice implies the law of the excluded middle.

Proof: Let $p$ be any proposition and consider the set $2 = \{0,1\}$. Let $A = \{x \in 2: (x = 0) \lor p\}$ and $B = \{x \in 2: (x = 1) \lor p\}$. Since $\{A,B\}$ is a set of non-empty sets there's a choice function $f\{A, B\} \rightarrow A \cup B$.

If $f(A) = f(B) = 0$ then $0 \in B$ so $(0 = 1) \lor p$. Since $0 \neq 1$ then $p$. Similarly if $f(A) = f(B) = 1$ then $p$.

Now if $f(A) \neq f(B)$ then $A \neq B$. If $p$ then $A = B = 2$, a contradiction. QED.

Now, the part I don't get is the last step. Why does $p$ imply $A = B = 2$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $p$ holds, then for every $x\in2$,$x=0\lor p$ is true since $p$ is true, and similarly $x=1\lor p$ is also true, so it must be that $A=B=2$.